# Charge a customer later on WooCommerce (Buy now and pay later!)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

Does anybody know of a way to charge a customer 30 days later on WooCommerce? We use Stripe as our payment method.

We want to allow customers to "Buy now and pay later"

I thought [WooCommerce Deposits](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-deposits/) would be perfect but unfortunately, they do not offer an automatic charge, you have to have the customer pay through a link later.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use Stripe's Charge API with the [auth and capture](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#auth-capture) flow. This way first you authorize the transaction - i.e. reserve the money on the account. To do this, you need to send a `capture: false` parameter when making the charge request.

Later you need to issue a [capture charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/capture) call, otherwise the auth will be released, meaning you won't get the money at all.

Read the docs on Stripe how long do they hold the `auth` part for, usually it's 7 or 14 days on other providers.